# Maintaining protected sheets/ranges when making copies in Google Classroom

Tags: protected

I've looked everywhere for an answer to this and I beginning to think there isn't one...

I'm sharing a google sheet with protected ranges by "making a copy for each student" when posting the assignment. By doing this, the owner of the spreadsheet gets changed to the student, thus making the protected ranges not apply to them any longer. There has got to be a way to make the ranges stay protected so students can't edit them?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Cory

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:
First: Add file, make a copy for each student. Then BEFORE (?) assigning the task to the students: In the classrooms Google drive, there will be a template folder where it says DO NOT EDIT, well I changed the protection of the whole sheet to "only I can edit"

Then I marked the cells where my students can edit and changed the protection range to allow the students to edit these specific cells. After that: press the "assign"-button. I hope it will work, I will find out tomorrow.

Nope, it's not working right now!